# CORS block / 504 Gateway Timeout with ng2-adsk-forge-viewer

Tags: angular, autodesk-forge

We are currently in the evaluation phase for the integration of the Autodesk Forge Viewer.

When showing the viewer (ng2-adsk-forge-viewer, latest version) we get CORS errors in the browser for a few days and the viewer/files are not loaded.
URN and Token are submitted correctly. The free trial is not expired and cloud credits are also available.

We have not changed anything in our implementation and cannot explain what it is due to.

Can anyone give us an advice?

Console output

```
Access to fetch at 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/res/locales/en/allstrings.json' from origin 'https://my.example' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field request-id is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
Access to fetch at 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/lmvworker.min.js' from origin 'https://my.example' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field request-id is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
Access to fetch at 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/dXJuOmFkc2 ... EuZHhm?domain=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.example' from origin 'https://my.example' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field request-id is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Request Headers

```
Request URL: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/res/locales/en/allstrings.json
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 504 Gateway Timeout (from ServiceWorker)
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown
accept: */*
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
DNT: 1
Referer: https://my.example
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:89141...
Request-Id: |4E...
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, your application seems to be requesting some of the viewer assets with an HTTP header `Request-Id` which is not allowed by the Forge servers. Do you know where that request could be coming from?

I've also noticed that the response is coming from a Service Worker - is that perhaps where the requests to the `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative` endpoint are intercepted and modified somehow?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer. We have investigated whether the problem is caused by the service worker. We found out that the problem was caused by a wrong Application-Insights configuration. The property `enableCorsCorrelation` was enabled. This added the HTTP header `Request-Id`.